# android motionlayout + exoplayer change orientation erro

Tags: android, surfaceview, exoplayer, android-motionlayout

I can not speak english. Please understand

When I click on the video image in the fragment to launch the requestOrientation landscape, the following error is exposed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0R2i.jpg)

If you don't use Motionlayout, that's fine.
please help........

fragment_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/playerMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_player_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:resize_mode="fill" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
</com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

frgment_player_scene.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="300">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="10"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/bottomTitleTextView" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="10"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/bottomPlayerControlButton" />
            <KeyPosition
                motion:curveFit="linear"
                motion:framePosition="10"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/playerView"
                motion:percentWidth="1"
                motion:percentX="1" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/playerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:2.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/playerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

activity_main_scene.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet></KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationY="56dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
    private lateinit var videoAdapter: VideoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        mainBinding = activityMainBinding

        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

        retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
        videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(callback = { url, title ->
            supportFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is PlayerFragment }?.let {
                (it as PlayerFragment).play(url, title)
            }
        })

        activityMainBinding.mainRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter = videoAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, PlayerFragment())
            .commit()

        getVideoList()
    }

    private fun getVideoList() {
        retrofit.create(VideoService::class.java).getVideoList()
            .enqueue(object : Callback<VideoDTO> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<VideoDTO>, response: Response<VideoDTO>) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful.not()) return

                    response.body()?.let {
                        videoAdapter.submitList(it.videos)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<VideoDTO>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "ERROR MESSAGE : ${t.message}")
                }
            })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mainBinding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

PlayerFragment

```
class PlayerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_player) {

    private var binding: FragmentPlayerBinding? = null
    private lateinit var videoAdapter: VideoAdapter
    private lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val fragmentPlayerBinding = FragmentPlayerBinding.bind(view)
        binding = fragmentPlayerBinding

        retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance()

        initRecyclerView(fragmentPlayerBinding)
        initPlayer(fragmentPlayerBinding)
        initControlButton(fragmentPlayerBinding)

        getVideoList()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(fragmentPlayerBinding: FragmentPlayerBinding) {
        videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(callback = { url, title ->
            play(url, title)
        })

        fragmentPlayerBinding.fragmentRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter = videoAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }
    }

    private fun initPlayer(fragmentPlayerBinding: FragmentPlayerBinding) {
        context?.let {
            player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(it).build()
        }
        fragmentPlayerBinding.playerView.player = player
        binding?.let {
            player?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
                override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                    super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)

                    if (isPlaying) {
                        it.bottomPlayerControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24)
                    } else {
                        it.bottomPlayerControlButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private fun initControlButton(fragmentPlayerBinding: FragmentPlayerBinding) {
        fragmentPlayerBinding.playerView.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }
    }

    private fun getVideoList() {
        retrofit.create(VideoService::class.java).getVideoList()
            .enqueue(object : Callback<VideoDTO> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<VideoDTO>, response: Response<VideoDTO>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful.not()) return
                    response.body()?.let {
                        videoAdapter.submitList(it.videos)
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<VideoDTO>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "ERROR MESSAGE : ${t.message}")
                }
            })
    }

    fun play(url: String, title: String) {
        context?.let {
            // url -> DataSource -> MediaSource -> Player
            val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(it)
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(url)))
            player?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            player?.prepare()
            player?.play()
        }
        binding?.let {
            // motionLayout end 결과 값으로
            it.playerMotionLayout.transitionToEnd()
            it.bottomTitleTextView.text = title
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        player?.pause()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
        player?.release()
    }
}
```

CustomVideoMotionLayout.kt

```
class CustomVideoMotionLayout(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null) :
    MotionLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    init {
        setTransitionListener(object : TransitionListener {
            override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
                (context as MainActivity).also { mainActivity ->
                    mainActivity.findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.mainMotionLayout).progress =
                        abs(progress)
                }
            }

            override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
                motionTouchStarted = false
            }

            override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {
            }
        })
    }

    private var motionTouchStarted = false
    private val mainContainerLayout: View by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.mainContainerLayout)
    }
    private val hitRect = Rect()

    private val gestureListener by lazy {
        object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onScroll(
                e1: MotionEvent,
                e2: MotionEvent,
                distanceX: Float,
                distanceY: Float
            ): Boolean {

                mainContainerLayout.getHitRect(hitRect)
                return hitRect.contains(e1.x.toInt(), e1.y.toInt())
            }
        }
    }
    private val gestureDetector by lazy {
        GestureDetector(context, gestureListener)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                motionTouchStarted = false
                return super.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
        }
        if (motionTouchStarted.not()) {
            mainContainerLayout.getHitRect(hitRect)
            motionTouchStarted = hitRect.contains(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event) && motionTouchStarted
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I try with exoplayer is adding   app:surface_type="texture_view" to
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView ..../>

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it:

announce this
`var isFullScreen = false`

```
// If you click on the fullscreen button on the player ('bt_fullscreen' is my custom control button)
bt_fullscreen.setOnClickListener {
            requestedOrientation = if (!isFullScreen) {
                bt_fullscreen.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_baseline_fullscreen_exit_24_white))
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
            } else {
                bt_fullscreen.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_baseline_fullscreen_24_white))
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            }
            isFullScreen = !isFullScreen
            if (isFullScreen) {
                motion_layout_id.getConstraintSet(R.id.start)?.let { // R.id.end is the ConstraintLayoutSet (put you your own ConstraintLayoutSet)
                    it.setVisibility(R.id.video_player_nestedScrollView_main, GONE)
                    it.constrainedHeight(R.id.motion_layout_main,true)
                    motion_layout_main.requestLayout()
                }
                motion_layout_id.getConstraintSet(R.id.end)?.let {
                    it.setVisibility(R.id.video_player_nestedScrollView_main, GONE)
                    motion_layout_main.requestLayout()
                }
            }
            else {
                motion_layout_main.getConstraintSet(R.id.start)?.let {
                    it.setVisibility(R.id.video_player_nestedScrollView_main, VISIBLE)
                    motion_layout_main.requestLayout()
                }
                motion_layout_main.getConstraintSet(R.id.end)?.let {
                    it.setVisibility(R.id.video_player_nestedScrollView_main, VISIBLE)
                    motion_layout_main.requestLayout()
                }
            }
        }
```